# where can I get the driver of imx219

Tags: kernel, driver, picamera

I'm building kernel(xilinx) and rootfs(debain10) for Avnet96v2 board which has connetted a imx219 via mipi adapter， where can I get newest official driver for the camera, if it is existing.

By the way, what kind of building I shall select for the driver, build-in or as module?

A manual is very kindly, and any recommendation will be welcomed.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because it is not open source. The Sony IMX219 includes crypto protection so the camera can't be cloned.

Comment: I saw some driver files for imx219 on web, is any of them valid?

Comment: Try them, See how fast they break. I don't have the hardware or the inclination to do that testing for you.